# How can I tell if my raycast hit a tree?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I have a [`TerrainGridSystem`](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/terrain-grid-system-47215) grid on a forested terrain.  The grid system draws a grid onto the terrain to set up a game board.  I want to find all the trees and mark the grid locations with a tree in them as impassable.

(For those unfamiliar with `TerrainGridSystem`, just assume everything does what you'd intuitively expect it does.  The question isn't about the grid.)

```
public class TreeDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TerrainGridSystem Grid;

    private static readonly Vector3 UP_HIGH = Vector3.up * 50;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (var cell in Grid.cells)
        {
            var pos = Grid.CellGetPosition(cell) + UP_HIGH;
            if (Physics.Raycast(pos, Vector3.down, out var info, 60))
            {
                if (HitATree(info))
                {
                    Grid.CellSetCanCross(cell.index, false);
                    Grid.CellSetColor(cell.index, Color.red);
                } else {
                    Grid.CellSetCanCross(cell.index, true);
                    Grid.CellSetColor(cell.index, Color.white);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to distinguish between hitting a tree and hitting the terrain.  When I hit a tree, `info.collider` is not the `CapsuleCollider` that was on the tree prefab; it's the `TerrainCollider`, and likewise `info.transform` is the Terrain object's transform.

Is there any reasonable way to implement `HitATree` that doesn't require ripping out all of the terrain trees and manually replacing them with `GameObject`s?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TerrainGrid but can't you create two of them? one for the base and one for the objects like trees, rocks, etc. , and then use tags to distinguish them. that's what I do in a tilemap

Comment: @ariankeshvari No, the trees aren't `GameObject`s.  They're part of the terrain.

Comment: If trees are part of the terrain, there may be some internals to distinguish which objects are present in the terrain ensemble. But TerrainGrid is a paid asset, so we can't just download it and try things out.

Comment: @liggiorgio See in the question, where I specifically say "the question isn't about the grid."  For the purposes of this question, all that's doing is setting up a bunch of cell locations that provide positions for me to check with raycasts.  The question is about the raycasts.

Comment: "The question isn't about the grid" unless your code fails because of a faulty grid displacement. Or because your ray casts start [from the wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62518607/4499313). Or because you're raycasting trees, but "trees aren't GameObjects but part of the terrain" (so, [children of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567132/unity-raycast-doesnt-work-for-the-child-objects-collider/42645271#42645271) or what?) Or because the problem is in the (not included) `HitATree()` method.

Comment: We can't "just assume things do what we'd intuitively expect them to". We need valid information to give solid answers, rather than assuming and guessing by trial and error.

Comment: @liggiorgio "Or because the problem is in the (not included) `HitATree()` method."  Once again, you're not reading the question carefully enough.  In the last paragraph I make it clear that what I'm trying to do is *figure out how to write* `HitATree()`.  That's the reason it's not included.

Comment: Alright, that was an oversight of mine :) Maybe `info.collider` lets you discriminate between the terrain and a tree instance? Or even better, you can assign your tree prefabs a special layer and check the collider's layer instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with Unity's terrain but skimming google this seems like a common issue, without an easy solution.

However for your case where you want to mark cells in the grid, you could probably just iterate through all the trees in the terrain (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html, the treeInstances property) and check which grid cells intersect with their bounds.